# How can I construct (instead of assign) an std::array element?

Tags: c++, constructor, assignment-operator, stdarray

I have a class that can't be re-assigned. The actual motive is that it has an `std::variant` member variable, and the possible types are not re-assignable, due to having some reference member variables (which can't be rebound). This is a very simple version of what we have:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(int a) {}
    MyClass(MyClass &other) = default;
    MyClass(MyClass &&other) = default;
    MyClass &operator=(MyClass &) = delete;
    MyClass &operator=(MyClass &&) = delete;
};
```

Now, at some point, I have an array of these objects.

```
std::array<MyClass, 5> my_array; // default initializes all objects
```

Eventually, I want to make a new object and put it into the array.

```
my_array[1] = {69};
```

But std::array tried to assign, and so I get an error.

```
error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass& MyClass::operator=(MyClass&&)’
   29 |     my_array[1] = {69};
      |                      ^
```

Is there a way to force reconstructing instead of reassigning the element?

Comment: The array handled by `std::array` is just like any other array. All elements are constructed when the array is created. All you can do is copy or move new values to the individual (and already existing) elements.

Comment: Optionally, though I really don't recommend it, you could use placement-new  to construct a new object in place of the one already existing in the element. It will force you to handle object life-time explicitly, and keep track if you already done a placement-new or not. It will complicate your code. As a somewhat similar (but still not something I would recommend) workaround you could use smart pointers as the element type.

Comment: `std::array<MyClass, 5> my_array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

Comment: Why do you have copy and move constructors but no assigment operations in your class? This design is just asking for trouble if you ask me. The rule of 3/ rule of 5 exists for a reason.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't think it's legal. Once you use placement new, you should also destroy the object manually, but on the other hand, the object has already been allocated on stack and its destructor will be called regardless of whether or not you used placement new. So on the one hand destructor must be called twice to avoid UB, but on the other calling the destructor twice is UB itself. To avoid it your array should originally be `char` array.

Comment: @chrysante But class does have assignment operations. No problem with rule 3/5

Comment: @Dmitry You could do `my_array[1].~MyClass(); new (&my_array[1]) MyClass(7);` Then the destructor would be called again when the array is destroyed. Not saying that this is a good idea, but it would technically be correct.

Comment: @user7860670 No, both overloads of `operator=` are deleted.

Comment: I guess the best solution would be to change the classes held be the `std::variant` to use pointer data members instead of reference data members and then provide assignment operators.

Comment: @chrysante Yes, both overloads of operator= are deleted so compiler will issue an error instead of silently doing something nasty with auto-genereted operators. So no problem here.

Comment: @chrysante One would have to placement-new the whole array to end and restart the lifes of all elements at the same time I guess? Or is it well defined to do a placement-new on a single element in an array like that? I'm thinking in terms of `delete` vs. `delete[]` but I'm not sure if the same reasoning applies here.

Comment: @user7860670 Yes, but isn't the error due to the deleted `operator=` exactly the point of the question?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That is a good point. I guess every major compiler would generate the expected code, but I'm not sure if it's technically legal.

Comment: @chrysante The point of the question is how to construct an array instead of assigning anything after initialization.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ask us about the actual and underlying problem instead. Right now your question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1):

No there's no way to force a reconstruction that wouldn't be undefined behaviour, at least not without destroying the preexisting element and using placement new.

Since you mention `std::variant` though: You can change the element type, even after the element is constructed regardless of whether the element type of the `std::variant` is copyable/moveable. Just use [`std::variant::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace).

The following example implements assignment operators in `MyClass` that make code similar to `my_array[1] = {69};` work.

```
struct IntHolder
{
    int& m_value;
    IntHolder(int& value)
        : m_value(value)
    {
    }

};

using Variant = std::variant<std::monostate, IntHolder>;

class MyClass
{
    Variant m_member;
public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(int& a)
    {
        m_member.emplace<IntHolder>(a);
    }

    // we'll remove both move and copy semantics for MyClass
    MyClass(MyClass&& other) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&&) = delete;

    MyClass& operator=(std::reference_wrapper<int> a)
    {
        m_member.emplace<IntHolder>(a);
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, MyClass const& value)
    {
        if (std::holds_alternative<IntHolder>(value.m_member))
        {
            s << "{ IntHolder { value = " << std::get<IntHolder>(value.m_member).m_value << " } }";
        }
        else
        {
            s << "{ std::monostate }";
        }
        return s;
    }
};


void Print(std::array<MyClass, 2> const& a)
{
    for (auto& e : a)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    std::array<MyClass, 2> arr{ x, y };

    std::cout << "after initialization\n";
    Print(arr);

    // "swap"
    arr[0] = std::ref(y);
    arr[1] = std::ref(x);

    std::cout << "after modification\n";
    Print(arr);
}
```